# Django DetailView: filtering object based off primary key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to filter an object based off of the primary key in my detailed view.  Is there a way I can call my primary key in my views.py or some other way I can filter accordingly?  Here's my code:

models.py

```
class Accounts(models.Model):
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pricing_id = models.ForeignKey('Pricing')

class OrderRecords(models.Model):
    order_id = models.ForeignKey('Orders')
    account_id = models.ForeignKey('Accounts')
    item_id = models.ForeignKey('Items')
```

views.py

```
class AccountDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Accounts

    template_name = "orders/accountdetail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AccountDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['orderrecords'] = OrderRecords.objects.filter(????????)
        return context
```

Update:

So this was the change I made:

views.py

```
class AccountDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Accounts

    template_name = "orders/accountdetail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        pk = self.kwargs['pk']

        context = super(AccountDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['orderrecords'] = OrderRecords.objects.filter(account_id=pk)
        return context
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in your views, simply call:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    pk = kwargs.get('pk') # this is the primary key from your URL
    # your other code
    context = super(AccountDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['orderrecords'] = OrderRecords.objects.filter(????????)
    return context
```

Comment: Okay, so I used: `pk = self.kwargs['pk']` and that worked.  Thanks!